# How to get message metadata in isolated Azure functions v4 - Queue Trigger in c#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I am following on a possible upgrade of azure function runtime from v3 to v4 with dotnet. While doing so, I am testing out the isolated option for the project. However I am unable to get message metadata such as DequeueCount, MessageId etc in the queue trigger.

Previously with in-process option, I used to bind `CloudQueueMessage` but that doesn't seem to work in the isolated mode. Doing so, throws and error -

```
Cannot convert input parameter 'myQueueItem' to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueueMessage' from type 'System.String'
```

This was my isolated queue function binding

```
[Function("TestApp")]
public void Run([QueueTrigger("sample-queue", Connection = "")] CloudQueueMessage myQueueItem, FunctionContext context)
```

After looking for a while, I think [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#usage) it says that, in isolated process we can only bind string. Simple JSON - Object also works.

[image]

Is there any way to get these message [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#message-metadata) (members of the `CloudQueueMessage`) in the isolated azure function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For DequeueCount property I use this:

```
[Function("MyQueueTrigger")]
public void Run([QueueTrigger("my-queue-name")] string myQueueItem, int dequeueCount)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Queue item: {item}. Dequeue count: {dequeueCount}.", myQueueItem, dequeueCount);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).